# Change control name in fast way

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need to put many controls on form during design. Each time I must scroll in Properties in order to find and change control name name. Is it possible somehow change controls name in fast way during design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but currently native Visual Studio does not have the function you want.

You can press `F4` on the control to quickly enter the property interface, but you need to find the Name property modification by yourself.

Using code modification is also an option if many controls need to be modified.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022